# Is this behavior a bug in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, typeerror, undefined-behavior

I'm rather new to TypeScript, so I'm not sure if I may/should use `Object.create(null)` to create a sort of 'static class', but since the TS compiler doesn't throw, it should be OK.

The bug I'm suspecting is that in case of using `Object.create(null)` to store properties/methods, the compiler doesn't throw an error in case of wrong arguments to a method.

I have this in one file, `index.ts`:

```
import {Mod} from './mod';
console.log(Mod.foo(33));
```

And this in the `mod.ts` file:

```
const Mod = Object.create(null);
Mod.foo = function(arg: string) {
  return arg + 1;
};
export {Mod};
```

As you can see, the foo method expects a string as an argument, but it's called with a number. And `$ tsc --build tsconfig.json` correctly compiles everything to js and no error is reported.

Also in this case the compiler also doesn't detect a wrong number of arguments, their order etc.

Could someone, who is experienced with TS say, if this is a bug or what?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: That's because currently `Object.create`'s return type defined as `any` which basically turns off the type checking (In above example `Mod` is of type `any`). There's a suggestion to add typed overloads https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/39882

Comment: TS does not play well with mutable values. If you want to  be type safer, define  a literal type with all methods